# Unreadable file attributes on windows

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems

Consider a following snippet of code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    int main()
    {
        WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA  wfad;

        GetFileAttributesEx(("C:\\TEMP\\noreadfile"), GetFileExInfoStandard, &wfad); //"noreadfile" is unreadable file
        std::cout << wfad.dwFileAttributes;  // 128                                                 
        return 0;
    }
```

For an unreadable file (File that does not have read permissions or file that has its read permissions set as "Deny" in its properties -> security tab) on Windows, `GetFileAttributesEx` returns `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL`, which means that [no other attribute is set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117(v=vs.85).aspx) for that file.

This attribute is also returned for a writeable as well as non-readonly files.

We use this information to set the permissions for files in our product code.

We concluded that `GetFileAttributesEx` might be returning incorrect attribute in case of unreadable files. We wonder if our conclusion is right or not.

If yes, then is this a known issue with `GetFileAttributesEx` ?

If not then

What is the correct way to get the file attributes (file permissions perhaps ?) for an **unreadable file** using Windows API or if possible using Boost or standard C++ filesystem libraries ?

Comment: File attributes (e.g. read-only, system, hidden, etc) are unrelated to file security. To get a file's discretionary access control list (DACL), call [`GetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446645).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not succeeding at all.  If you look at the [documentation for GetFileAttributesEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946(v=vs.85).aspx), it actually returns a BOOL.

> Return value If the function succeeds, the return value is a nonzero
>   value.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero (0). To get extended
>   error information, call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx).

My guess is that "fwad" is undefined if the call fails.  Try checking the return value for a failure indication.  My guess is that GetLastError will return something like [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx).

The Windows API doesn't throw exceptions, so unfortunately you'll have to check just about every return value.

Comment: It's correct that the OP should check for success, but it's unlikely that reading file attributes would fail in this case, even if the file security denies the right to read them. The OP is very likely to have the right to list the parent directory, "C:\Temp". This implicitly allows reading the attributes of any file in the directory.

Comment: Similarly, delete-child access to the directory allows deleting any file that doesn't have the read-only attribute set, even if a file's security doesn't allow it. These are the two cases where the parent directory security trumps that of a contained file.

Comment: Odd...  The generic "read" access is [supposed to](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(v=ws.10).aspx) include "read attribute", but as far as I can tell, I can see all of the attributes of all files as long as I can list the directory they're in.

Comment: That's by design. File attributes have to be available when listing a directory, so the right to list the parent directory always grants the right to read file attributes.

Comment: This assumes the calling program is running as a user who has permission to access the directory in question. If it is a directory owned by another user, access is likely to be denied

Comment: @RemyLebeau, just being owned by another user doesn't imply that you'll likely be denied the right to list (read) the directory. But if it's another user's profile directory, and you're not running as an administrator or system, then, yes, you won't have any access. But I stipulated from the start that the likelihood of access here is because the directory is "C:\Temp", which by default inherits an ACE that grants read and execute access to all users. This can be overridden, which is why I only said it's "very likely" the OP has the right to list the directory.

Comment: Interesting.  If I create a file I can access and put it in a directory I can't access or list, I can view its contents and attributes (as expected -- I have the "bypass traverse checking" privilege).  However, unless I grant myself the "read attributes" permission, I can't even read the data.  I'm not entirely sure how "read attributes" is useful as a standalone permission.

Comment: Going back to the original question...  You are talking about read-only in the original DOS attribute sense, not the permission sense?  If you want to see if a file is effectively read-only for the *current user*, you might need to use the [AccessCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374815(v=vs.85).aspx) function after first using [GetNamedSecurityInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645(v=vs.85).aspx).  You can more easily just use [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @DavidA, WinAPI `CreateFile` requires read-attributes and synchronize access at a minimum. NTAPI `NtCreateFile` or `NtOpenFile` don't require these rights, except synchronize access is required for the `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_[NON]ALERT` option. However, if you open a handle without read-attributes access, calling `GetFileTime` and `GetInformationByHandle` will fail since the I/O Manager's `FileBasicInformation` info class requires this right.

Comment: @DavidA `GetFileAttributesExW` function returns non zero value with file attribute as `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` for unreadable file as described above.  We have already tried using `CreateFile` after it and it returned correct error `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` which seems to be one of the approaches discussed in the comments.